# How to generate SOAP 1.2 Version endpoint with JAX-WS and Maven

Tags: web-services, maven, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

So I am trying to consume a WSDL with SOAP version 1.2 with JAX-WS, however it will only generate version 1.1. I am using Maven to consume the WSDL. The POM file consuming of the WSDL looks as follows.

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>

    <executions>
      <execution>
       <goals>
          <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>MEAI_OnlineServices.webServices.Volubill_selfCare_04.wsdl</wsdlFile>
          </wsdlFiles>
          <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/wsdl</bindingDirectory>
          <extension>true</extension>
          <protocol>Xsoap1.2</protocol>            
        </configuration>
      </execution>

    </executions>

  </plugin>
```

The following are snippets from the WSDL

```
   <wsdl:definitions name="selfCare" targetNamespace="http://eaidev.mobinil.com/MEAI_OnlineServices/webServices/Volubill/selfCare" 
   xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
   xmlns:soapjms="http://www.w3.org/2008/07/soap/bindings/JMS/" 
   xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
   xmlns:tns="http://eaidev.mobinil.com/MEAI_OnlineServices/webServices/Volubill/selfC
   are" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
   xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
   xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
```

Then when declaring the oeperations I have the following.

```
    <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="deleteBucket">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="MEAI_OnlineServices_webServices_Volubill_selfCare_Binder_deleteBucket" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap12:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap12:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I cannot manage to get this building a 1.2 version. I have 2 bindings files as follows that will prevent parts of the WSDL generating void methods instead of return methods.

jaxb-binding.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!-- Prevent any Strings being changed to a JAXBE<String> element -->
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" />     
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And bindings.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <bindings xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
wsdlLocation="MEAI_OnlineServices.webServices.Volubill_selfCare_04.wsdl"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
<!-- Disable default wrapper style -->
<enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>  
<endpoints xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime' version='2.0'>
<endpoint binding="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/"/>
</endpoints>
```

The endpoints in the bindings class were an attempt to get it to generate SOAP 1.2 but I was met with no success.

Does anyway have an idea of how to fix this? If more code is needed just let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem. Just wondering if you found a solution for this or not. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Sorry about late reply, I am afraid I cannot really remember the exact solution. I remember it had to do with when the generator was being called in Java, there was an extra option that would allow you to set the version. Sorry about the vague answer but it was a fair while ago and no longer have access to the code base! Hope it helps a little at least.

Comment: Anyone with the solution to this problem? this seems to be the problem for many people

Answer (score 0):

The following config worked for me:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>com.helger.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>periodictableaccessws</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>your_wsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <packageName>your.target.package
                        </packageName>
                        <target>2.1</target>
                        <keep>true</keep>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```